# Hadoop: Windows build - Maven Error

Tags: apache, maven, hadoop, maven-plugin

I am working on a Windows 2012 Server R2 environment and I have downloaded Hadoop 2.6.0 and have been following the instructions given from these sources:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J61R-eVRmzc
2. https://mariuszprzydatek.com/2015/05/10/installing_hadoop_on_windows_8_or_8_1/

However, when I try to run the command "mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar" in my C:\hdp\ folder I get an error.

Please find below a screenshot of the error:

[image]

I am not sure what the error could be.

My environment is set as follows:

#### User Variables:

PATH : C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin.;C:\Windows\System32;

#### System Variables:

HADOOP_HOME : C:\hadoop-2.6.0\bin
JAVA_HOME : C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_92
M2_HOME : C:\apache-maven-3.2.5
Platform : x64
Path :  C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin.;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\protoc.exe;C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\protoc-2.5.0-win32;C:\cygwin64\bin

Pointers and advice on how to proceed please.

Comment: It could be network issue. or some issue related to ~/.m2/settings.xml. what is the ip 151.101.12.215 for?

Comment: It is the IP address for Apache - USA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a proxy / connection error.
Was able to download it from another PC/ another network.